# AWS Fargate container authentication configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, credentials, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

What would be the appropriate way to configure infrastructure independent parameters inside Docker container inside ECS?

Let's say there's an API that needs to be connected with external sources (DB for example that doesn't live inside AWS infrastructure). How would one configure the container to discover the external sources?

What I've come up with:

- Environment variables;
- Injecting configuration during Docker image building;
- Using AWS System Manager Parameter Store;
- Using AWS Secrets Manager;
- Hosting the configuration in S3 for example and reading from there.

To me using the environment variables seems to be the way to go. 
Because one wouldn't want to make an extra query to the AWS System Manager or Secrets Manager just to get the DB host & port every time connecting with the external source.

Another possibility I thought about was that after the container is started the required parameters are queried from the AWS System Manager or Secrets Manager and then stored in some sort of configuration file. But how would one distinguish then between test & production?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: How do you differentiate between test and production containers?

Comment: FYI you can have parameter store values show up as environment variables, so you don’t have to explicitly read them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I would like to use the same container for test and production. What differs should be the configuration.